# window.onload without global variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use windows.load without global variable.

The HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="txt1"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Check Input" id="b1">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript global variable code:

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/

var myButton;

window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    myButton = document.getElementById("b1");
    myButton.addEventListener("click",alertMM);
};

function alertMM() {
    "use strict";
    window.console.log(myButton.value);
}
```

And finally the NOT WORKING without global variable code:

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/

var myNS = {
    myButton: undefined,
    //
    setUp: function () {
        "use strict";
        myNS.myButton = document.getElementById("b1");
        myNS.myButton.addEventListener("click", alertMM);
    }
};

window.onload = myNS.setUp();

function alertMM() {
    "use strict";
    window.console.log(myNS.myButton.value);
}
```

The reason that I want to stop using global variable is that I'm afraid it will conflict with future code.

Thanks in advance

Adrian

Comment: BTW, you could use `this.myButton = ` as an alternative to `myNS.myButton =`. Probably a matter of personal preference in this case...

Comment: you can use the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) pattern and wrap eveyrthing in a self executing function, which sets an inner scope and won't let variables leak to the global scope

Comment: or you can define `alertMM()` inside your onload function and use the same `myButton` object

Comment: Actually you should clearup this code. If you are using addEventListener, use it everywhere, don't need to fallback to `window.onload` thing. Improve your namespace with module pattern. It will make your code more strict and easer to understand. When you need to assign method - use the closures `window.onload=function(){..}'

Comment: What do you mean, "use it everywhere, don't need to fallback to window.onload thing", can you give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In:

```
window.onload = myNS.setUp();
```

when you define the `window.onload` callback, you should assign it the function itself (just `myNS.setUp`) so it can be called later. What your code doing instead is calling the function immediately and assigning the result.

Comment: Hope it's clearer that way, @Matt Browne. You're welcome to edit otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable scoping in JavaScript is primarily function scope oriented. As in, functions enclose their inner variables. So you could avoid polluting the global scope simply by declaring your variables (and assigning the DOM el) within the function that you're assigning to `window.onload`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //variable assignments inside the function
  var button1 = document.getElementById('b1');
  var button2 = document.getElementById('globalCheck');
  //anonymous functions attached instead of named functions
  button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(button1.value);
  });
  button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("var button1 in the global scope: " + window.button1 + "\n" + "var button2 in the global scope: " + window.button2);
  });
};
```

```css
.greyButton {
  background-color: grey;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 30%;
}
#txt1 {
  width: 29%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="Name" value="">
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Check Input" id="b1" class="greyButton">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Are the variables global?" id="globalCheck" class="greyButton">
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```